# how to log client ssl handshake logs in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx for my servers and the nginx is being used as ssl termination point.

Now I want to know the SSL handshake details of client. For example the Certificate information, cipher, protocol etc.

I have dig the internet and found the way to log the cipher and protocol but the handshake log is still not available.

Comment: Have you read docs? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables

Comment: yeah but it does not provide my data, most of the variables return blank.